# React Router not working properly, elements remain on page after redirection

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple Index for debug purposes, my issue is that whenever I click one of the links, the index itself remains there, example:

The index elements are at the top, and then the elements of the login page itself.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oo63E.png]

I know it's an issue with the Routes, but I can't get it to work:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import Login from './Login';
import Registro from './Registro';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/Login">Go to Login</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/Registro">Go to Registro</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Index />} />
          <Route exact path="/Login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route exact path="/Registro" element={<Registro />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

const Index = () => {
  const [userEmail, setUserEmail] = useState('');
  const [nombre, setNombre] = useState('');
  useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (token) {
      const decodedToken = jwtDecode(token);
      console.log(decodedToken)
      const nombre = decodedToken.usernombre;
      const email = decodedToken.userEmail;
      setUserEmail(email);
      setNombre(nombre);
    }


  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Index simple</h1>
      <h2>Correo: {userEmail}</h2>
      <h2>Nombre: {nombre}</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<App />);
```

I tried using a Switch, but I couldn't import it for some reason, as I've read, it's been changed to "Routes" but that didn't work either.

Comment: Is your question about the `<nav />` remaining on all routes? I don't see any redirection in your code. Can you clarify what you mean by "index"? I see an `Index` component in your code but in your question it sounds like you're referring to the `<nav />` element.